# find a non diagonizable 3x3 matrix with precisely one real eigenvalue of multiplicity 1

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, diagonalization

can someone help me with this question

Question: find a non diagonizable 3x3 matrix with precisely one real eigenvalue of multiplicity 1?

Thanks

Comment: Try a rotation matrix.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The jordan-block
$$\begin{pmatrix}1&1&0\\0&1&1\\0&0&1\end{pmatrix}$$
is not diagonizable and has one real eigenvalue namely $1$ with multiplicity 1.